# Elaboration on the uniform randomness of selection of a key

Tags: algorithm, probability, clrs

Consider this question:-
[Efficiently picking a random element from a chained hash table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8629447/5345646)

And consider it's first answer. It suggests a method to select a key in a uniformly random fashion. That, however, is unclear to me. The first step would take  a probability of `1/m` (i.e randomly selecting a bucket from m buckets)
And the second step can be divided into two steps:
1) If `k<=p`, then p is returned.
2) If `k>p` then the loop again runs.
This is done until p is returned.
So the probability of a key being selected is :
`(1/m)[(k1/L)+((L-k1)/L)[(1/m)[(k2/L)+((L-k2)/L)[(1/m)[(k3/L)+((L-k3)/L)[......and so on.`
Now how can this be equal to `1/n`?

Comment: You repeat both steps until success, not just the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a form of [rejection-sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).

#### Remark:

- it looks like you splitted the two steps and loop somehow on the second step only (my interpretation of your calculation-formula)
- **redoing all steps** every time is the most important aspect of the algorithm!

  - it's the basic-idea of rejection-sampling: we are sampling from some surrounding-density and need to sample again, if the selected sample is not within the range of our sample range (that's very informal; read the above link)

#### Why this approach:

- Imagine, there are **2 buckets**, where **b0** hast **2** elements, **b1** has **4** elements
- **Step 1** is selecting one bucket **uniformly**

  - But because **b0** has a different amount of elements than **b1**, the actual sampling in **step 2** needs to be somehow adapted to the information about the number of elements (or we will use uniformity)
  - We don't have this full information, we only got the **upper-bound L on all chains**
  - Meaning: We use the **rejection-idea** to sample from the **max-range L**; and **accept if the index is compatible** with the bucket. So if the selected bucket has half the amount of elements compared to the biggest one, it needs to be aborted (restart with step 1) 50% of the time. **It's like inserting fake-elements to all buckets so that the amounts of elements are constant. Then sample, check if real or fake-element was selected and do that again if a fake one was hit**.
  - It's easy to see that: **b0** get's chosen 50% of the time; equal to **b1**
  - When sampling within **b0**, the process will get **aborted** 50% of time, because **k=2, L=4** (L from the size of elements in **b2**)
  - When sampling within **b1**, the process will never get aborted (**k=L**)
  - If there would be no chance of aborting; we would select one selected element of **b0** *2 times as often* (`L / size-within-b0 = L/2`) as one from **b1**, because the bucket is uniformly selected; but the number of elements to sample from differ.